# why my MVC route registration doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, global-asax

I have

Controller:

`[MySite]\Controllers\DistributionTools\TrackingChannelsController.cs`

```
[HttpPost]
public void InitTcFirstPageView()
{
    var model = new TcFirstPageModel
                    {
                        BestChannel = new BestChannel()
                    };
    View("~\\Views\\DistributionTools\\TcFirstPageView", model);
}
```

View:

`Views\DistributionTools\TcFirstPageView.aspx`

Global.asax:

```
    routes.MapRoute("TrackingChannels", "TrackingChannels/{action}",
        new { controller = "TrackingChannels", action = "InitTcFirstPageView" });
```

Yet when I surf to 
`http://localhost:85/TrackingChannels/InitTcFirstPageView`

I get

[image]

Comment: Is the class name 'DistributionTools' or 'DistributionToolsController'? Because that would make a difference.

Comment: An Action returning  `void` ??

Comment: I agree with Henk Holterman. The returntype should be ActionResult and you should return the View. If you have to do some initialization you could derive from controller and override the Initialize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HttpPost] attribute means that Action will only handle POST requests.  You need to remove that attribute, or test using a POST.

Comment: @Elad I think Jon below found another issue.  One more thing-- I don't recognize what you're doing for 'InitTcFirstPageView'.  Maybe it's MVC2 syntax or something, but shouldn't an action have "ActionResult" as a return type?

Comment: can I avoid registering the rout somehow?

Comment: Well, normally when you create an MVC3 project in Visual Studio it sets up a default route for you, which is {Controller}/{Action}, with defaults of Controller="Home" and Action="Index".  But you have to have at least one route registered ...

Answer (score 1):

TrackingChannels is not the name of the controller is it? You said it was DistributionTools so your route should be:

```
routes.MapRoute("TrackingChannels", "DistributionTools/{action}",
        new { controller = "DistributionTools", action = "InitTcFirstPageView" });
```

Comment: `it's [MySite]\Controllers\DistributionTools\TrackingChannelsController.cs`
can I avoid registering the rout somehow?